# How to create hash table from nested array (php)

Tags: php, arrays, hashtable

I have a nested array with the information I need.

```
array(66) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["key"]=>
    string(1) "9"
    ["value"]=>
    string(1) "9"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["key"]=>
    string(3) "104"
    ["value"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["key"]=>
    string(3) "105"
    ["value"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
...
```

However, this format is not terribly useful. More useful would be

```
[9]=>9
[104]=>3
[105]=>1
```

and so on.

Unfortunately my attempt

```
foreach ($arrayname as $key => $value) {
             $i= ((int) $value);
             $hashmap[$i] = ($value["value"]); 
            }
```

to date merely records the final value, without the associated key
array(1) { [1]=> string(3) "360" }. Note: it doesn't matter if the key is stored as string or int!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is already an array of hashmaps. So you should use it that way.
You are not interested in the keys `0, 1, ..` here I suppose.

```
$hashmap = array();
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    $hashmap[$value["key"]] = $value["value"]; 
}
```

Your can then use the key/value pair foreach method to check that this worked:

```
foreach($hashmap as $key => $value){
    echo 'map['.$key.']='.$value." \n<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your array is two-dimensional. So the first dimension represents a key/value pair. Your solution is taking the key from the first dimension and not the second.

```
$hashmap = [];
foreach($arrayname as $pair) {
    $key           = $pair['key'];
    $value         = $pair['value'];
    $hashamp[$key] = $value;
}
```